# Flutter image_picker plugin crashes the app while selecting image from gallery (only on specific devices)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, crash, imagepicker

I have used **image_picker** latest version **0.6.7+4**.

Issue:
image picker opens a gallery for selecting images but after scrolling through almost 100-500 images when i select an image the main.dart gets killed abruptly due to which in some devices the app crashes(oppo, mi) & in some it just go back to the first screen.

OS: both Android and iOS
Flutter version: stable **v1.17.5**

Comment: Which Android version?

Comment: minSdkVersion 21, targetSdkVersion 28

Comment: And you will not mention those devices as we would know them already?

Comment: One sure device is OnePlus 7 Android 10. I don’t have oppo device details with me.

Comment: Think that it is because of Android 10. What does that image picker deliver? An uri or a file system path?

Comment: Ideally it should return a file system path. But it just crashes without returning any result or exception. Read lot of issues with image_pickers main activity getting killed but i am not sure it is a case over here as well.

Comment: i have the same problem when i pick the image and return to app my app starts from the beginning. how did you solve this problem?